# How would I go about accessing a computer server which I could surf the Internet on through another computer?

Tags: server

I’m new to this website well I’ve never made a question but I’m just trying to find a general direction to go into. If this is the wrong place I’m sorry about that. However Can anybody direct me on how I would approach creating a server on a computer which I can use for the internet through another computer. The reason I want to do this is so I can by pass my schools wifi block by hopefully connecting to my computers server (still unsure where to start on this or even have a clue so if anyone can give me an idea or what I need to do or learn, it would be a great help) at home by internet up or if I could by using a usb in which I connect to my computers at school.

The reason I’d prefer some type of usb is that I can’t access many things on the internet due to them being blocked through the school server.

If this is unclear and you need more of an explanation I’d happily will or if you can tell me where I should post this or what website.

Comment: If you own the computer and can set the web browser to use a proxy, I would use SSH. First, install a SSH server on your home PC (or any PC outside the school with unrestricted access to the Internet). Then, configure PuTTy (a SSH client) to provide a SOCKS proxy and connect to the remote PC. Finally, set your browser to use the SOCKS proxy. It's worth noting that this most likely violates your school's network terms of use and may result in disciplinary action.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can’t wait to dive into all of that tomorrow and hopefully I’ll have something set up in under a month (good at coding but a newbie at everything else). Also how does one have such vast knowledge to think of just an idea or even the solution, how did you gain all that knowledge, sorry if it seems weird but my high school is extremely slow teaching computer science and I want to be able to go past the whole lot and study more advanced things earlier